# How to wrap a mqtt client around an existing tcp socket?

Tags: node.js, sockets, typescript, tcp, mqtt

I'm in a situation in which I need to wrap a `mqtt.Client` around an existing tcp socket to access some info about the just opened connection (e.g. localAddress and localPort). Is it possibile to do something like this in typescript?

```
import * as mqtt from 'mqtt';
import * as net from 'net';
class Client
{
    private _client: mqtt.Client;
    private _socket: net.Socket;

    constructor()
    {
        this._socket = net.createConnection({host: 'my_host', port: 1234}, () => 
        {
            this._client = new mqtt.Client(this._socket, {
                // options here.
            });

            // Access the socket info
            // this._socket.localAddress
            // this._socket.localPort
        });
    }
}
```

Or maybe is there another way to reuse the same tcp socket opened by `mqtt.connect` function?
Thank you for any help!

I'm using this [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) to implement the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it working tweaking with the mqtt API.
In case you encounter this problem just get the info you need from the embedded `stream` object stored inside the client.
Something like this:

```
import * as mqtt from 'mqtt';
class Client
{
    private _client: mqtt.Client;

    constructor()
    {
        this._client = mqtt.connect(`mqtt://${URL_GOES_HERE}`, {
            // options here.
        });

        this._client.on('connect', () =>
        {
            let address = this._client.stream.localAddress;
            let port = this._client.stream.localPort;
        });
    }
}
```